# Ubuntu Touch Documents Viewer wont Install

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I am trying to install the Document Viewer on Ubuntu Touch. I had it installed before but entered read-write mode, and screwed things up. Therefore I reflashed Ubuntu Touch using,

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap --wipe
```

This appears to have reinstalled Ubuntu Touch, but I can't install Document Viewer. When I try it downloads to 100% then says "Download or install failed. Please try again.". Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand right? You have first entered RWMode and then you reflashed the device?

Comment: Yes. After entering RWMode I reflashed the nexus 7 using the command in my original question.

Comment: I tried making a new ubuntu one account but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was on OTA 9 and after I upgraded to OTA 10 the document viewer installed without issue.