# 'Document Viewer' app won't download to M10 tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, downloads, pdf

I started up my new Aquaris M10 tablet today. Managed to download a couple of apps successfully from the Ubuntu Store. However, when I downloaded
'Document Viewer', it failed at the end - - 4 times! Obviously there is something wrong with the app, which I need desperately to read PDF's. The M10 manual says file formats include PDF and txt, but they don't show up from my SD card.

Comment: Do you get any error message during installation? Or is the actual issue, that it cannot open the pdf from your sd card?

Comment: The only error I got, was that the download (after the bar reached 100%) had failed. Jurjen has hit the nail on the head with the OS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. There is an O.S. upgrade available which you have to install first. The document viewer only installs on the latest O.S. version, and that is newer than the one the tablet was shipped with.

Edit: OTA 10 is the desired version: [Ubuntu Touch Documents Viewer wont Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754740/ubuntu-touch-documents-viewer-wont-install)